# I have N+1 problem but fetch join seems dosen't work

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Relation of tables are

```
USER(N) - (1)Follow_Shop(1) - (N)Shop
```

and Follow_shop has PK of USER, SHOP AS FK

So the Follow_SHOP columns are

```
id || user_id(PK of USER) || shop_id(PK of SHOP)
```

The result that I want to get is information of shop in shop table via follow_shop table

So I try this query to get shop data

```
    @Query("SELECT distinct fs FROM FollowShop fs JOIN FETCH fs.shop JOIN FETCH fs.user WHERE fs.user.id=:userId ")
    List<FollowShop> findMyFollowShopById(@Param("userId") Long Id);
```

Find shop_id with user_id in Follow_shop table and take info of shop with shop_id

And to avoid N+1 Problem I use fetch join, but the hibernate query go out like this

```
2022-02-11 04:22:27.411 DEBUG 50469 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user0_.id as id1_7_, user0_.created_at as created_2_7_, user0_.modified_at as modified3_7_, user0_.auth_provider as auth_pro4_7_, user0_.email as email5_7_, user0_.nickname as nickname6_7_, user0_.password as password7_7_, user0_.phone_number as phone_nu8_7_, user0_.profile_img as profile_9_7_, user0_.provider_id as provide10_7_, user0_.refresh_token as refresh11_7_ from users user0_ where user0_.email=?
2022-02-11 04:22:27.422 DEBUG 50469 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_6_0_, roles0_.roles as roles2_6_0_ from user_roles roles0_ where roles0_.user_id=?
2022-02-11 04:22:27.437 DEBUG 50469 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user0_.id as id1_7_, user0_.created_at as created_2_7_, user0_.modified_at as modified3_7_, user0_.auth_provider as auth_pro4_7_, user0_.email as email5_7_, user0_.nickname as nickname6_7_, user0_.password as password7_7_, user0_.phone_number as phone_nu8_7_, user0_.profile_img as profile_9_7_, user0_.provider_id as provide10_7_, user0_.refresh_token as refresh11_7_ from users user0_ where user0_.email=?
2022-02-11 04:22:27.439 DEBUG 50469 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_6_0_, roles0_.roles as roles2_6_0_ from user_roles roles0_ where roles0_.user_id=?
2022-02-11 04:22:27.452 DEBUG 50469 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user0_.id as id1_7_, user0_.created_at as created_2_7_, user0_.modified_at as modified3_7_, user0_.auth_provider as auth_pro4_7_, user0_.email as email5_7_, user0_.nickname as nickname6_7_, user0_.password as password7_7_, user0_.phone_number as phone_nu8_7_, user0_.profile_img as profile_9_7_, user0_.provider_id as provide10_7_, user0_.refresh_token as refresh11_7_ from users user0_ where user0_.email=?
2022-02-11 04:22:27.454 DEBUG 50469 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_6_0_, roles0_.roles as roles2_6_0_ from user_roles roles0_ where roles0_.user_id=?
2022-02-11 04:22:27.458 DEBUG 50469 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select distinct followshop0_.id as id1_2_0_, shop1_.id as id1_4_1_, user2_.id as id1_7_2_, followshop0_.shop_id as shop_id2_2_0_, followshop0_.user_id as user_id3_2_0_, shop1_.address as address2_4_1_, shop1_.bellscore as bellscor3_4_1_, shop1_.image as image4_4_1_, shop1_.latitude as latitude5_4_1_, shop1_.longitude as longitud6_4_1_, shop1_.name as name7_4_1_, shop1_.runtime as runtime8_4_1_, (select count(*) from follow_shop where follow_shop.shop_id=shop1_.id) as formula1_1_, user2_.created_at as created_2_7_2_, user2_.modified_at as modified3_7_2_, user2_.auth_provider as auth_pro4_7_2_, user2_.email as email5_7_2_, user2_.nickname as nickname6_7_2_, user2_.password as password7_7_2_, user2_.phone_number as phone_nu8_7_2_, user2_.profile_img as profile_9_7_2_, user2_.provider_id as provide10_7_2_, user2_.refresh_token as refresh11_7_2_ from follow_shop followshop0_ inner join shop shop1_ on followshop0_.shop_id=shop1_.id inner join users user2_ on followshop0_.user_id=user2_.id where followshop0_.user_id=?
```

As you know the "SAME" query goes out 3times!! I dont know why;
And the query selects all USER entity field and try to take it.
But actually I don't need USER info this time.
And To avoid this n+1 problem I use "Fetch Join" on my query but it seems like, It dosen't work....
Am I wrote wrong grammar?

ADD extra info of my code

service layer code

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<MyFollowShopResponse> myFollowShop(User user) {
        List<MyFollowShopResponse> followShops = followShopRepository.findMyFollowShopById(user.getId()).stream()
                .map(MyFollowShopResponse::from)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return followShops;
    }
```

Controller layer code

```
    @GetMapping("/follow/shop")
    public ResponseEntity<?> myFollowShopList(@RequireLogin User user) {
        List<MyFollowShopResponse> list = followService.myFollowShop(user);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(list);
    }
```

MyFollowShopResponseDto

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyFollowShopResponse {

    private Long shopId;

    private String shopName;

    private String profileImg;

    public static MyFollowShopResponse from(FollowShop followShop) {
        return new MyFollowShopResponse(followShop.getShop().getId(), followShop.getShop().getName(), followShop.getShop().getImage());
    }
}
```

follow_shop db data -> has 5 datas

```
id || user_id || shop_id
-------------------------
1  ||   1    ||    1
2  ||   2    ||    1
3  ||   3    ||    1
4  ||   1    ||    1
5  ||   4    ||    1
```

shop db -> has 2 datas

```
id || name ......
--------------------
1 ||  dd
2 ||  dddd
```

user db -> has 4 datas

```
id || name || .......
-----------------
1
2
3
4
```

matching data with user_id = 1 in follow_shop tables only two

and postman came out same result which I expected.

result of postman

```
[
    {
        "shopId": 1,
        "shopName": "dd",
        "profileImg": "1"
    },
    {
        "shopId": 1,
        "shopName": "dd",
        "profileImg": "1"
    }
]
```

Comment: The 3 repeated queries are "find user with email=? and the user's roles". This doesn't seem to be related with the "SELECT DISTINCT ..." query. It would help if you showed more of your code.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Colud you check again please? I added more information of my status (code, db, result)